# git release on unique repo and different modules - correct way for versioning

Tags: .net, git, versioning

I have a .NET main project so structured:

```
main solution
    - core project
    - ui project
    - cli project
    - unittest project
```

Since the repo is just only one where belongs the main solution and therefore the modules on their subdirectories, what is the correct way to make a release / hotfix for each sub project?

If I start a release with version x, the branch release takes ALL the modules, but in fact I want only a module to tag and release.

A possible solution might comes on making a unique version tag that takes ALL the modules, no cares if a module is increased of version or is not changed at all.

What do you think about that?

Comment: If you want to git-version (like history-wise and tag-wise) the individual modules *individually*, you cannot store them in one repository.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to not tag or release the entire tree. Create tags with names that name what you tag: `cli-1.7.2`, `core-4.19.1`. Create 4 different release processes that release subdirectories instead of the entire tree.

Comment: but the url repo is only one, if I try to start a release from the subdirectory the release itself involves ALL the directories and modules

Comment: Sorry, by the word "release" you mean tags at Github?

Comment: The git tag command. 
In the ordinary I use git flow release start, which on closing create automatically a corresponding tag for the release itself

Comment: git flow is rather primitive IMO and if you gonna use it you probably need to split your monorepo into separate subprojects.